# XAMPP - Change @INC path to direct to Activeperl 5.12.2 LIB

Tags: perl, perl-module, www-mechanize, activeperl

I currently have XAMPP installed at C:\xampp.  I currently have Activeperl installed at C:\Perl64.

How can I get my XAMPP server to utilize the library in activeperl instead of the built in library in xampp when executing perl scripts?

Answer (score 0):

set your PERL5LIB environment variable to point into the ActivePerl lib directory.
I don't have the exact incantation for you. I switched from ActivePerl to Strawberry Perl this summer right after YAPC::NA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cgi/fastcgi application, it is good to point to your AP installation with shebang at the script top:

```
#!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe
```

The libraries will go along.

It might get more complicated if you have perl built into Apache with mod_perl, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add environment variable PERL5LIB -> `your lib path` in user variables.Follow the below steps:

   - Right click on my computer and go to property
   - Click advanced system settings
   - Click Environment variables
   - In system variables click new
   - In variable name type PERL5LIB
   - In variable value type `path to lib folder`

Or run following for windows in command prompt:
`set PERL5LIB=c:\code\lib`

Or run following for Linux:
`export PERL5LIB=/home/code/lib`

Now open apache2\conf\httpd.conf in Notepad++ and do following changes

- Add Perl library folder paths anywhere in the file.
  `SetEnv PERL5LIB C:/code/lib;C:/usr/site/lib;C:/usr/lib`
- save the config and restart the apache service.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable in httpd.conf. Like described [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570410/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-apache-xampp) Settings take effect after restarting Apache. I put this line:

```
SetEnv PERL5LIB=C:\Strawberry\perl\lib;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib
```

Worked great with Strawberry Perl.