# how to set environment variables in apache xampp ?

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I would like to add some environment variables in apache xampp in windows.
I already tried the following : 
adding this in httpd.conf

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "setting"
```

or, run this script

```
putenv("ENVIRONMENT='setting'");
```

but that doesn't seem to work when I echo phpinfo(), there isn't ENVIRONMENT variable in the environment section

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is an old post and the OP already may has solved this by himself but for others:

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT setting
```

This would be the correct Syntax inside of the httpd.conf file. Also, this code should be put at the end of the file.

After saving httpd.conf the apache server needs to be restarted. Otherwise the environment variable will not be set in "this" apache session!

Sincerely,
Kami Yang

Answer (score 0):

**No server restart required** if you add your environment variables to a **.htaccess** file in your code directory. For example if you have a PHP app under the directory `P:\xampp7.3\htdocs\MyTestApp`, add a `P:\xampp7.3\htdocs\MyTestApp\env-test.php` script and copy the line of code below into it:

```
<?php echo getenv('APPLICATION_NAME'); // print APPLICATION_NAME environment variable ?>
```

Next create a `P:\xampp7.3\htdocs\MyTestApp\.htaccess` file and add:

```sh
SetEnv APPLICATION_NAME "Testing my application environment variable"
```

When you run the `env-test.php` script, it should print

```
Testing my application environment variable
```